# Yii bootstrap - TbGridView and select/filter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

How should I implement bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView with filters in columns ? I want to use http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ (multiple select) instead of normal select.

```
$columns = array(
    'test'=>array(
  'name'=>'test',
  'header'=>'test',
  'value'=>'implode(", ", $data->get())',
  'filter'=> CHtml::listData(Group::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
);

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'id'=>'person-grid',
'type'=>'striped condensed',
'dataProvider'=>$modelSearch,
'filter'=>$filter,
'selectableRows'=>2,
'enableHistory' => true,
'responsiveTable'=>true,
'columns'=>  $columns

));
```

The goal is to be able to select/filter data view with few values(in one column) instead of just one ? There is an example http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap-select/ but how it should be used with bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView

Comment: by "multiple select" do u mean multiple filter criteria at a time? If you are searching by name then you can add like "Thomas,chin,Eric"? Do you want like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add html to filters. Just rememeber to set the widgets [`captureOutput`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#widget-detail) to `true` i.e

```
'filter'=>$this->widget('...',array(...),true),
```

In addition you will probably have to edit your search function to process the multiple entries.